# Помогите решить задачу на JS без использования строковых методов

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Дан текст (строка), содержащий в себе  группы  букв, цифр, символов. Преобразовать текст, отсортировав каждую группу букв по алфавиту, каждую группу цифр в порядке убывания. Например: «cba1076 /’abfc3785,’’3946f»  - «abc7610 /’abcf8753,’’9643f»  . Не использовать строковые функции

Comment: Что получилось до сих пор? Добавте ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Все что вам нужно это разбить строку на массив и воспользоваться какой-либо сортировкой. Например

```js
var myString = 'cba1076 /’abfc3785,’’3946f';

function myBubbleSort(myArray) {
  var n = myArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n-1-i; j++) {
      if (myArray[j+1] < myArray[j]) {
        var t = myArray[j+1]; myArray[j+1] = myArray[j]; myArray[j] = t;
      }
    }
  }                     
  return myArray;
}

var myResult = myBubbleSort(myString.split(''));
alert(myResult);
```

Comment: Насколько я понял из условия, String.split нельзя использовать. Можно циклически перебрать строку, обращаясь к каждой букве по индексу (как при работе с массивом).